# Segmentation fault during insertion of node into linked list

Tags: c, linked-list

I am attempting to alphabetize two separate lists in my add function: one that sorts the nodes by first names, and another that sorts by last names. I also have some logic that checks if a name is already in the list and if it is an error is printed and the list is returned unchanged. Like the title says, I am getting a segmentation fault here and am not sure why. It may be a pretty basic problem but I am new to `C` and especially new to linked lists.

Here is how the nodes are defined:

```
typedef struct node {
    char *first;
    char *last;
    long number;
    struct node *nextFirst;
    struct node *nextLast;
} Node;

typedef struct mlist {
    Node *headFirstName;
    Node *headLastName;
} MultiLinkedList;
```

And here is my add function:

```
MultiLinkedList *add(MultiLinkedList *list, char *first, char *last, long num) {
    // allocate a new node
    Node *newNode = malloc ( sizeof(Node) );
    newNode->first = malloc ( strlen(first) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->first, first);
    newNode->last = malloc ( strlen(last) + 1 );
    strcpy(newNode->last, last);
    newNode->number = num;
    //make placeholder nodes
    Node *a = list->headFirstName;
    Node *b = list->headLastName;
    // add this new node at the head of the "byFirst" list
    if (strcmp(newNode->first, a->first) < 0) {
            newNode->nextFirst = list->headFirstName;
            list->headFirstName = newNode;
    }
    for (Node *i = list->headFirstName; i; i = i->nextFirst) {
            // add after less alphabetical nodes
            if (strcmp(newNode->first, i->first) > 0) {
                    newNode->nextFirst = i->nextFirst;
                    i->nextFirst = newNode;
            }
            // return error for duplicate name
            if (strcmp(newNode->first, i->first) == 0 && strcmp(newNode->last, i->last) == 0) {
                    printf("That person is already in the list! Please try with a different name.\n");
            }
    }
    // add this new node at the head of the "byLast" list
    if (strcmp(newNode->last, b->last) < 0) {
            newNode->nextLast = list->headLastName;
            list->headLastName = newNode;
    }
    for (Node *j = list->headLastName; j; j = j->nextLast) {
            // add after less alphabetical nodes
            if (strcmp(newNode->last, j->last) > 0) {
                    newNode->nextLast = j->nextLast;
                    j->nextLast = newNode;
            }
    }
    // return the multi-list object with updated or original head pointers
    return list;
}
```

Comment: May I suggest that you compile in debug mode and use that debugger to run the program ? That way, you'll be able to find the exact line where the segfault is happening, narrowing down the search quite efficiently.

Comment: what happens if `list->headFirstName` is NULL when the list is empty? the function seems to assume there always is a list.

Comment: To avoid clutter I would also suggest you move out all code that has to do with initializing the Node and put into a separate function where you initialize all members. e.g. Node* MakeNode(const char* first, const char* last)

Comment: @AndersK. `list->headFirstName` will always be NULL when the list is empty because it has nothing to point to

Answer (score 1):

I figured out what my problem was. I had to add `return list;` to the end of each if statement otherwise the function attempts to perform every true statement; which causes the seg fault. In hindsight I'm surprised I didn't figure this out sooner.